# How to pass meta description through Facebook like button without og tags?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

Is it possible to pass the meta description through the Facebook like button without using the og tags?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I have this tag currently

```
<meta name="description" content="description here" />
```

but i don't have access to update it to

```
<meta property="og:description" content="description here" />
```

I'd like to pass "description here" along with the title and URL. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered the JavaScript SDK? Specifically it's worth a look at FB.ui which can be used to create the same interface as the like plugin but you can configure all of the fields. More info available at http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: right, i've been using this reference http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ but there's no attribute i can see for meta description without using the "og" tags

Comment: You cannot do it with that plugin, that's why I suggested the JavaScript SDK and FB.ui.  Here's the link to what you need to do (includes the example code) http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Comment: But the only way to do it with the plugin is to use the "og" tags, correct?

Comment: Believe that's correct, yes. To be certain, use the URL linter that's linked from the like plugin page you've linked to above and this will tell you what info it can derive from your page's meta data http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: Can you update the link to the facebook javascript sdk? the link you provided doesn't show it any more.